# NFC motion sticker for monitoring breathing

Tags: smartphones, wireless, wearable-technology

I'm looking for an NFC sticker that can be stuck onto someone's rib, that can be used to detect the motion of the rib. This would be used to work out breathing patterns and abnormalities to enable a device to send an emergency alert in case of breathing difficulties. It must be compatible with Android.

Comment: Interesting inquiry. I'm curious how it would differentiate chest contraction/expansion from other bodily movements if it were as simple as a sticker.

Comment: @jatuttle0 I'm imagining that if the device is strapped to the person axially to the sensor, then that might be how.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this grew too big to be a comment.

NFC does not give any indication of distance. Weeeell, I suppose that theoretically you could try to measure signal strength - from expansive active RFID, not NFC, tags, not cheap passive tags - but that is absolutely not off the shelf & would require a great deal of expertise, eve if it is doable.

BLE 5.1+ has the option of Angle of Arrival/Departure which allow location to within 1cm (which might also mot be accurate enough), so that seems to be your best bet.

My question [BLE 5.1 wearable dev board](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/ble-5-1-wearable-dev-board) has received no answers, though :-(

Answer (score 1):

To detect expansion (and hence contraction), the normal thing to use would be strain gauges.  I have used them on extensively before, but not on people, but it has been proposed..

- Article on Nature.com [Respiration rate and volume measurements using wearable strain sensors](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41746-019-0083-3)
- Article on iudel.edu [Measuring Breathing Patterns through Strain Gauges](https://sites.udel.edu/coe-engex/2017/04/06/measuring-breathing-patterns-through-strain-gauges/)
- Article on National Library of Medicine [Respiration rate and volume measurements using wearable strain sensors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6550208/)

Search for `Strain Gauges` or `Wearable Strain Gauges` to find actual devices.