# BLE 5.1 wearable dev board *with AoA and AoD*

Tags: bluetooth-5

Having has no success with my question [BLE5.1 with on-board eInk (or any kind of display)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/ble5-1-with-on-board-eink-or-any-kind-of-display), I will contemplate an alternative.

Let's swap the display for wearability. Is there a BLE 5.1 dev board with battery attachment (preferably a cell type battery, but any is acceptable) - no soldering required?

Please note that it must be at least BLE 5.1, as previous versions, including BLE 5.0, do not support the AoA/AoD which I seek. Just to be clear, I am not looking for any 5,.1 dev board, only a dev board which supports AoA and AoD.

[Update] an on-board debugger would be preferable, although I can live with a JTAG probe (or even print over serial port)

Comment: Note that AoA/AoD are optional features of BLE 5.1. You can have a BLE 5.1 chip/board without AoA/AoD support. The latter requires additional hardware (a phased array antenna). Nordic have a dedicated chip for that (nrf52811), but thy don't have a full DK supporting direction finding. So if you want AoA/AoD, you must be explicit about it, just BLE 5.1 is not enough for that.

Comment: [Bluetooth vs Ultra-Wideband (UWB): which is best for indoor location system?](https://www.pointr.tech/blog/bluetooth-vs-ultra-wideband-which-technology-to-use-for-indoor-location), although, as a seller, they may be biased. I was not aware of UWB until your question & am quite excited :-) Hmmm, see "3 Challenges of Ultra-Wideband for Indoor Location" at that link. Looks like BLE, certainly for the next few years ? What do you think, and why?